# Rails 4: How Can I filter records that have no has_many records matching a certain criteria?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is the problem that I am having: 
I have an app with a `questions` object, which has_many `answers`. Answers have a status attribute, which can be equal to `accepted`.

How can I write an ActiveRecord query that will return only questions that have zero accepted answers? This is what I have tried currently:

```
 class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :answers

   def self.needs_answers
     self.includes(:answers).group('questions.id').where('answers.id IS NOT NULL OR answers.status != 'accepted').references(:answers)
   end
 end
```

However, if a question has 2 answers, one that is accepted and one that is not, it will still be returned by this query. How can I filter these records out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be other ways with a complex `COUNT`-based join/having, but the simplest way I can think to solve this is using a sub-select:

```
def self.needs_answers
  where.not id: joins(:answers).where(answers:{status: 'accepted'})
end
```